# Number of indices exceeds the number of dimensions of the indexed array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio, vb6, vb6-migration

I have a project that I have converted from VB6 to VB.NET using Visual Studio 2008. I have an line of code that throws an error in compiling. The line of code worked well in VB6.

```
For OccIndex = 0 To CDbl(glArrCuts(8, CutsIndex)) - 1
```

I am not sure how to rewrite the code to make it work in VB.NET. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: So whats the definition of glArrCuts? PS first Time I've seen a for loop on a double, nevere would have thought of that myself.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the definition of `glArrCuts`.  The definition of value is a single dimensional array yet you are using it as a multidimensional array.  The definition for `glArrCuts` looks like the following

```
Dim glArrCuts As TheType()
```

The `()` here ask for a single dimensional array.  To declare a multidimensional array the declaration needs to look like the following

```
Dim glArrCuts As TheType(, )
```

Notice the `,` in the declaration.

Comment: I will try what you suggested. Thank you for time and input.